What is the example of the following rule in the Java specification?
JLS 5.1.6.2 (emphasis mine):

The unchecked narrowing reference conversions are as follows:

A narrowing reference conversion from a type S to a parameterized
class or interface type T is unchecked, unless at least one of the
following is true:

...
<
– T <: S, and S has no subtype X other than T where the type arguments
of X are not contained in the type arguments of T.




class T<A> extends S<A> {
    
}

class  S<L> {
     
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        T<String> pc=(T<String>) new S<String>();
        //T<String> is a subtype of S<String>.So no warning will be given.
        
    }
} 

I  have a little difficulty understanding this sentence "type arguments of X are not contained in the type arguments of T".
As shown in the above example, T(T) is a subtype of S(S).
If I want to make S have another subtype X, and the type arguments of X is contained in the type arguments of T (according to the specification, this should give a warning,this is exactly the situation I hope for.), Then how should such code be written?

"But I can only think of the situation where T is a subtype of S". Well I'd surprised if you thought of anything other than that. The JLS says "T <: S".

@Sweeper  What I mean is that I can only write code that satisfies T <: S. For the latter part, I can't think of it. Do you have any good insights?

Your code already satisfies the latter part. If it didn't, you would have gotten a warning. What do you mean by "how should I improve the above code?"

What I think you might be asking for, is an example that satisfies T <: S, but does not satisfy the latter part. Please edit your question to clarify that.

@Sweeper  You are right. This is precisely the kind of example I need. I have revised my question and am eagerly awaiting your response.

The meaning of the word "contain" is the reflexive and transitive relationship between type arguments as defined in 4.5.1. Intuitively, if type argument T1 contains another type argument T2, then the set of types that are represented by T2 is a subset of the types represented by T1.
Because of this condition, casts from List<? extends Number> to ArrayList<? extends Integer> are deemed unchecked. List<? extends Number> has a subtype ArrayList<? extends Number>, but ? extends Number is not contained in ? extends Integer.
On the other hand, casts from List<? extends Integer> to ArrayList<? extends Number> are perfectly safe (i.e. not unchecked), because all the subtypes of List<? extends Integer>, such as List<Integer>, have type arguments that are contained in ? extends Number.
Now you might say, but what if I made my own generic implementation of List<Integer>?
class Foo<T> implements List<Integer> { ... }

Then List<Integer> would have a subtype Foo<String>, and now definitely-safe casts like from List<Integer> to ArrayList<Integer> would be unchecked! String is not contained in Integer, after all.
While this would be true if we interpret the JLS literally, this is not its intention. This cannot possibly be its intention, because what if Foo has a different number of type parameters? The "contains" relationship is not defined for those cases.
Looking at the JLS for Java 6, we can see that this bullet point used to say:

T <: S and S has no subtype X != T , such that the erasures of X and T are the same.

This was too prohibitive - the aforementioned cast from List<? extends Integer> to ArrayList<? extends Number> would be deemed unchecked.
As a result, JDK-6558557 was filed to change that bullet point to its current wording. Its intention was to make this more permissive. Casts from List<Integer> tp ArrayList<Integer> was not unchecked as per Java 6's spec - the intention of this change could not possibly have been to make that unchecked.
I think it is safe to assume that X also needs to have the same erasure as T, in addition to having type arguments that are not contained in T's type arguments.

I can understand the first two paragraphs. But why is  List<? extends Integer>  a supertype of  ArrayList<? extends Number> ? According to my understanding, to find the superclass of  ArrayList<? extends Number> , first perform capture conversion, so it becomes  ArrayList<X1> , and  X1  has an upper bound of  glb(Number) , that is,  Number . Then  List<X1>  can be a supertype of  ArrayList<X1> . Now if  List<? extends Integer>  is a supertype of  List<X1> , then it can be proven. But how does  ? extends Integer  contain  X1 ?Or, is there any other way to prove it?

@user24723440 Oh you're right. Seems like another error they made while changing the spec. It should be clear from context that this is clearly a mistake in the JLS, since the whole point of this change is to allow conversions like I1<Integer> to I2<? extends Number>.

@user24723440 Lots of your recent questions show mistakes from the JLS, so great job of finding them! It would be even better if you can report them on https://bugs.openjdk.org.

I am just a student. I am not sure if this is a mistake. My last question is, why is  Foo<String>  a subtype of  List<Integer> ?

@user24723440 Foo literally implements List<Integer>.

Foo<String>  is a parameterized type. Now, according to the content of 4.10.2, find its supertype. Which clause does it correspond to?I don't think  List<Integer>  is "The substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn] applied to the direct superinterface types
of List".Because the direct superinterface type  List<Integer>  cannot be replaced at all.Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

@user24723440 Indeed there is nothing to replace, but there is no contradiction. After applying the substitution, List<Integer> is still List<Integer>, and that's the direct supertype.

But this does not match my experimental results. If there is:class  S<L> {  }
class T<A> extends S<String> {  },   for: T<String> pc=(T<String>) new S<String>(); T<String> a subtype of S<String>,But my compiler gave me an unchecked warning.  Why?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
